# How can I install gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev on Windows 10?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to install scipy libray with pip but I got many errors on command line , one of these error is :

```
   raise NotFoundError(msg)
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No BLAS/LAPACK libraries found.
  To build Scipy from sources, BLAS & LAPACK libraries need to be installed.
  See site.cfg.example in the Scipy source directory and
  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/building/index.html for details.
```

However, To resolve this issue , I found many solution that describe how to avoid these problems .

One of solution that I've found is to install these libraries before install scipy :

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev
sudo pip install scipy==1.2.1
```

**Source :** https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9005

This solution will works on Windows , but I didn't found how can I install these packages on Windows , What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by downgrade my python version from `3.10` to `3.7.9`

Answer (score -1):

lo que pasa es que es posible que este tipo de librerias ya no sea compatible con las nuevas versiones de python.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your language , please update your answer